# Arduino Solar GPS tracker

Tags: wireless, arduino, gps, tracking-devices, asset-tracking

I am looking to create a solar powered GPS tracker for a fleet of rental trailers.  I am intermediate Arduino user and comfortable with this platform and would like to base it on this system.  Requirements are:

1. Uses cellular system to report.
2. Solar powered - there is no native power on the trailer.
3. IoT reporting (I will secure a subscription for reporting/recording)
4. Ardunio based.

Design freedom:

1. Can be bulky.
2. Does not need to be covert.
3. Does not need fast reporting - a position every hour or even every day would be sufficient.

Comment: Not going to vote to close, but this might be a bit big of a project for this site. I'll see if I can help out.

Comment: Sure thing, I get that... I can figure out the coding and assembly.  It's the component selection that I'd be interested in.  Does that reduce the scope sufficiently to keep the topic open?

Comment: That was clear in your original post, just wanted to let you know that there's not many with the requisite expertise in all those areas to provide quality recommendations on the component selection. I can try and help out, but unfortunately, I'm not sure I know enough of what I'm doing to give solid recs.